# How is this particular site finding my location? http://freebirds.com/locations/

Tags: javascript, geolocation

IP geolocation always seems to get me wrong (it returns the town my ISP is based in, which is 180 miles east of here), so I am wondering what they are using. However, I couldn't tell by looking at their source. Did I miss it or are they doing something server-side?

I'm using a desktop browser. I tried it in Chrome 17 and IE 7 and it worked in both apps.

Comment: I didn't see anything in the code that would indicate that it's client side.

Comment: If there's nothing client-side, does that mean it HAS to be IP-based geolocation? Or is there another way?

Comment: Well the browser isn't asking you to share your location, so it's not using HTML5 to geolocate you. I would guess it's server side, and just checking your IP against a database.

Comment: Thanks j08691. I don't see much happening with this, so if you move/copy your comment to an answer, I'll mark it as such and we can wrap this thing up =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't see anything in the code that would indicate that it's client side. The browser isn't asking you to share your location, so it's not using HTML5 to geolocate you. I would guess it's server side, and just checking your IP against a database